# Overlapping bell pairs in quantikz

Tags: diagrams, overlap, quantikz

Does anyone know how to draw overlapping Bell/qubits pairs using quantikz as shown below?

[image: overlapping bell pairs]

Really appreciate it.

Comment: You can start by repeating the example on page 14 of the manual twice.

Comment: The second qubit can't go below the third qubit. I can't figure out how to make them overlap.

Comment: Sure, but the idea is that you post your complete compilable code in your question, showing where you're stuck.  People will help if you show your effort.